# Why is Bootstrap color not working for rows?

Tags: html, css

Bootstrap colour is not applied when running the below for `row` and `div`:

```css
.row>div {
  padding: 20px 
  background-color: #32CD32 !important;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2 id="social">
  <center> Follow Us On The Socials!</center>
</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      FaceBook: SuperShoes
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      Instagram: SS_Shoes
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      Twitter: SuperShoesCompany
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      SnapChat: Super_Shoes
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      Youtube: Super Shoes
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

r is not applied when running the below for `row` and `div`:

Comment: you are missing a semi-colon after `padding: 20px`

Comment: Don't use `<center>`. Voting to close as off-topic since the issue is due to a typo

Comment: The center attribute is to keep my text in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide proper information about the question. the code should be in proper format
and also you don't have to provide your social media usernames. here we only try provide you proper solutions so give proper information about your query...

As above information please give a semicolon after padding

```
.row > div { 
             padding: 20px;
             background-color: #32CD32 !important; 
             border: 2px solid black; 
          }
```